# Filtrar datos apartir de una tabla CSV

Tags: c#, excel, csv

Tengo un archivo ASCII y este hago la conversión desde excel y lo separo por espacios o también con comas.

Pero quiero filtrar únicamente unos datos con toda su fila que tienen un patron en común (9999) y en base a este crear una nueva tabla que contenga los datos anteriores y al final hacer una sumatoria del tiempo. Este es un ejemplo de mi tabla:

```
Fecha,     Tiempo,  Error, Dato2,Dato3
21092016, 07:09:50,  5.2,   AA,  BB
21092016, 07:10:30,  9999,  AA,  BB
21092016, 07:11:50,  4.2,   AA,  BB
21092016, 07:12:10,  5.2,   AA,  BB
21092016, 07:15:20,  9999,  AA,  BB
21092016, 07:17:53,  9999,  AA,  BB
21092016, 07:18:10,  5.2,   AA,  BB
21092016, 07:19:00,  4.2,   AA,  BB
```

Podria hacer una tabla dinamica, pero lo curioso de este filtrado es que al momento de jalar la fila que contenga 9999 quiero que también filtre el dato proximo que no contenga 9999 osea (4.2 o 5.2 o menor a 9999). Esto con la finalidad de contar el tiempo que tardo ese error que seria mas o menos asi como deberia verse la tabla final:

```
  Fecha,     Tiempo,  Error, Dato2, Dato3, TiempoError
    21092016, 07:10:30,  9999,  AA,  BB,    00:01:20 (Resta 07:11:50 - 07:10:30)
    21092016, 07:11:50,  4.2,   AA,  BB,       -
    21092016, 07:15:20,  9999,  AA,  BB,    00:02:50 (Resta 07:18:10 - 07:15:20)
    21092016, 07:17:53,  9999,  AA,  BB,       -
    21092016, 07:18:10,  5.2,   AA,  BB,       -
    21092016, 07:20:10,  5.2,   AA,  BB,       -
    21092016, 07:21:10,  4.2,   AA,  BB,       -

                        TOTAL TIEMPO ERROR: 00:04:10
```

Que lógica me ayudaría a detectar el dato próximo, después de un 9999? 
que me recomienda hacer, programación c# para csv? Macros de excel? Tablas dinámicas?

Se los agradecería mucho! Saludos

Comment: En la penúltima fila me parece que falta `TiempoError = 00:00:17` ¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET estas en lo cierto, fue mi error, Gracias por la observación! ya lo corregi

Comment: @DavidTod se puede hacer hasta incluso con una simple fórmula en Excel... hay algún motivo para hacerlo por código?

Comment: @Mariano No, aunque seria un plus hacerlo por ahí ya que se necesitara para "n" archivos csv que deseen filtrar, pero si es lo que pensaba con una formula pero no se me ocurre la lógica para encontrar el registro próximo después de un 9999 y mas en excel que no me gusta

Comment: @DavidTod Debe haber varias formas. Una muy sencilla: agregar una columna auxiliar que calcule `[ProximoTiempo]`. Si `[Error] = 9999`, obtener el valor de la celda de abajo, sino obtener el valor de `[Tiempo]`... Luego en `[TiempoError]`, si `[Error] = 9999`, mostrar `[ProximoTiempo] - [Tiempo]`, sino `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo visto es un **CSV** sencillo, es decir que los campos no incluyen el `string NewLine` ni la coma. Por lo tanto desde **c#** puedes procesar el archivo como texto, [►](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) extrayendo las lineas que se comportan como registros:

```c#
string path = "ruta del archivo CSV";
string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Luego con un bucle `for` se puede recorrer registro por registro, en busca del error `9999`:

```c#
for ( int i = 0; i < lineas.Length - 1; i++ )    { /* ... */ }
```

El `-1` es importante para impedir que se pase del límite del vector; porque dentro del bucle se accederá a la línea indexada por `i`, y en caso de corresponder con el error `9999`, entonces se intentará leer la línea `i + 1`, de lo que se deduce que `i` puede tomar como valor máximo `lineas.Length - 2`

Ejemplo para la solución:

```c#
// Establece la ruta completa del archivo CSV.
string path = @"A:\CSV.txt";

// Lee todas las líneas del archivo CSV.
string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

// El resultado se mostrará en un DataTable.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Fecha");
dt.Columns.Add("Tiempo");
dt.Columns.Add("Error");
dt.Columns.Add("Dato2");
dt.Columns.Add("Dato3");
dt.Columns.Add("TiempoError");

// Acumula el total de la diferencia de tiempos.
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;

// Campos para las líneas que se leerán en el bucle for.
string[] campos1, campos2;

// Bucle for para recorrer línea a línea.
for ( int i = 0; i < lineas.Length - 1; i++ )
{
    campos1 = lineas[i].Split(',');

    int num;    Int32.TryParse( campos1[2], out num);

    // Verifica la condición solicitada.
    if (num == 9999)
    {
        campos2 = lineas[i + 1].Split(',');

        // Lee los tiempos para obtener la diferencia.
        DateTime dt1, dt2;

        // TryParseExact() permite especificar un formato personalizado,
        // en este caso es "ddMMyyyyHH:mm:ss"
        DateTime.TryParseExact(campos1[0].Trim() + campos1[1].Trim() , "ddMMyyyyHH:mm:ss",
                               null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt1);
        DateTime.TryParseExact(campos2[0].Trim() + campos2[1].Trim() , "ddMMyyyyHH:mm:ss",
                               null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt2);

        // Las operaciones entre DateTime siempre se deben realizar con TimeSpan.
        TimeSpan dif = dt2 - dt1;
        total += dif;

        // Se agrega al DataTable la fila del tiempo inicial.
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1.ItemArray = campos1;
        // Incluye la diferencia entre los tiempos de ambas líneas.
        dr1["TiempoError"] = dif.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

        // Agrega al DataTable la fila del tiempo final, si no cumple
        // con la condición Error == 9999.
        // En caso de cumplir con dicha condición, esta línea será
        // evaluada en la siguiente iteración.
        // Así se evita la duplicación de la fila.
        Int32.TryParse(campos2[2], out num);
        if (num != 9999)
        {
            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2.ItemArray = campos2;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
        }
    }    
}
// Agrega la línea que muestra el total de TiempoError.
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();            
dr[4] = "Total tiempo error:";
dr[5] = total.ToString();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

// Muestra el resultado en una DataGridView.
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Tener en cuenta que `9999` es lo que se suele llamar [*número mágico*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), por lo que conviene usar una constante para el mismo.

Enlaces de interés:

- [DateTime.TryParseExact (Método)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Estructura TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-10)

Comment: Excelente logica, se complemento perfectamente a mi proyecto, muchas gracias master!